# UPD Перезаписываются после потери соединения к RDS

Tags: администрирование, windows-server, smb

Есть с десяток серверов с ролью RDS, и настроенной коллекцией сеансов. Диски пользователей хранятся на SBM сервере. Все сервера win2019, и расположены в одном vlan. Суть проблемы такая - если пользователь работает в данный момент, скажем на srv-rd1, а хранилище по какой то причине недоступно(пропал интернет, отмаунтился диск, упал гипервизор и тд). Пользователь попадает во временный профиль, естественно из него он не выйдет, но при восстановление хранилища и перелогине, его основной диск, заменяется на временный. Из за чего это происходит, и как бороться? Спасибо

Comment: Специфичная фигня. Не пробовал у майков на форуме спросить? Сильно не факт, что тут быстро помогут.

Comment: весь интернет перекопал, конкретного разбора проблемы так и не нашел

Comment: Ну а журнал чё-нить в это время говорит интересное?

Comment: На сервере хранения ничего важного, на рд что пользователь не удалось получить свой профиль, и будет использован временный, про замену основного на временный не слова, не в одном из журналов

Comment: Происходит из-за того, что в реестре для каждого SID прописан путь к профилю. Когда профиль не доступен - создается дубликатная запись для того же SIDа, после чего в нее происходит логин. Необходимо удалить дубликаты.